# How to make something similar to a registered model in the admin module

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make an app that fills the database.
I create a file named "filldata.py" in all my apps.
This file imports the package.
Then I implemented a callback function and is registered in the package
filler.register (mycallback)
I have a general application in which I implement a terminal command that fills the database.
This is similar to the implementation of registration models in the admin module.
This code is the implementation of a terminal command. And he did not like it. I think there is a better pythonic way to implement this import

```
import importlib

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        filler = None
        for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            try:
                filler = importlib.import_module(app + '.filldata')
            except ImportError:
                pass
        if filler:
            filler.filler.sort_callbacks()
            for msg in filler.filler.fill():
                self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(msg))
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like reinventing the wheel. You should definitely look at the [providing initial data docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/). Data migrations or fixture loading should provide valid alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I understand! But it need generate data using external resources and it has dependencies between self.

Comment: `if filler:` should be inside the `for` loop.